# Expose debugging symbols for a program compiled with multiple languages

Tags: c++, c, gcc, gdb

As per official instructions, to compile a program with debugging support you can run

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O0 -g -c -o program1.o program1.cpp
```

Now to do the same with a C program, it's just:

```
gcc -O0 -g -c -o program2.o program2.c
```

In order to link both types together, I could use:

```
g++ --std=c++11  -O0 -g -o program program.o program2.o
```

Then, to debug:

```
gdb program
gdb > run <PARAMS>
```

It worked completely after several attempts at tinkering with the compiler options (the above options are for a working version). In some cases the C symbols would load, but the C++ symbols would not.

Can someone shed some light as to what the recommended options are to enable debugging for non-trivial examples that mix several compiled languages? All of the documentation only refers to trivial examples.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but executable programs are not supposed to have the `.so` suffix, it's for *Shared Object* (i.e. dynamic libraries, or a DLL). On POSIX systems like Linux or OSX executable programs usually have no suffix.

Comment: As for your question, GCC always uses the `-g` option to add debug information, no matter the language. Disabling optimization with `-O0` is also a good idea. That's about it.

Comment: the link step also needs the `-g` option.  And if the debugging is going to be via `gdb` then the correct option for both compile and link steps is `-ggdb` as that makes even more information available that `gdb` can use.

Comment: when the compile/link statements are missing the `-std=...` option, the the compiler will use what ever the default standard is. (usually c89 or similar)  So all the calls to gcc (and/or g++) should reference the appropriate standard.

Comment: the `gdb` utility can only, automatically, find the source file when it is in the same directory as the executable.  For all other cases, the source file(s) must be specifically loaded.

Comment: @aphid Your question is contains a vague allegation that something didn't work. *Show* us what that was.

Comment: I seem to have missed the -g option on the linker step, I did use it via the makefile (hence why it worked) but it didn't get copied to the question, Question was edited.

Comment: "the C++ symbols would not" how do you know? Always provide relevant output and/or error mwssages.

Comment: I knew that the C++ symbols didn't load by simply asking gdb which files or symbols were loaded. I could view the C file, but not the Cpp file from the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each compilation and linking step, add the `-g` option to the compiler flags. `-O0` is recommended too for debug builds so you don't get the compiler optimizing functions away. Being inconsistent may result in no debug symbols or partial debug symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you use just the `-g` option then the compiler will use operating system's native format, which can vary. You can explicitly specify the format instead, using other `-g...` varieties (for example `-gdwarf-3` or `-g-stabs`). This allows you to guarantee that your object files will all have a consistent debug format, irrespective of where they were built.

You can also disable `gdb`-only extensions by using this approach, should you wish to use other debuggers. See [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) for details.